# Adding custom dictionary to SpellCheck class

Tags: c#, wpf

I Faced with the problem of checking the spelling: I made a dictionary (http://yadi.sk/d/YIPIfIfEBBTuj), as it says here http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.controls.spellcheck.customdictionaries.aspx

I added it to the TextBox:

```
<SpellCheck.CustomDictionaries>
     <System:Uri>pack://application:,,,/Dictionaries/Russian.lex</System:Uri>
</SpellCheck.CustomDictionaries>
```

But it does not work (from where the characters 'Enter' took in dictionary? => spell check does not work):

[image]

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

File on your link does not match the required format.

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.controls.spellcheck.customdictionaries%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Here is an example of the required format: #LID 1033
TextBlock
TextBox
listboks

That is, for a dictionary of the Russian language you need to add in the beginning of the file: #LID 1049